# Windows 10 スタートメニューのタイル定義情報はどこ？

Tags: windows, windows-10

表題の通りの質問なのですが、Windows10のタイル情報はPC内のどこにあるのでしょか。
ご存知の方いましたらご教授ください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10では定義場所そのものは公開されていませんが、管理者が制御可能になっていました。[スタート画面のレイアウトのカスタマイズとエクスポート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout)で説明されています。

> 次のいずれかの方法を使って、結果の .xml ファイルをデバイスに展開することができます。
>
> - グループ ポリシー
> - Windows 構成デザイナーのプロビジョニング パッケージ
> - モバイル デバイス管理 (MDM)

実はこれだけでなく、PowerShellに[`Export-StartLayout`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt188237.aspx)と[`Import-StartLayout`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt188241.aspx)とが用意されていますので、得られたXMLファイルで自由に編集できるかと思います。

---

タイル定義情報はどこ？とのことですが、プログラムからアクセスすることを前提とした質問と推測します。
これについては、[The contents of the Start page are not programmatically accessible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141029-00/?p=43743)で

> A customer wanted to know if is possible for an application to edit the user's Start page.
>
> No, there is no interface for editing the user's Start page or even knowing what is on it. The Start page is the user's personal space and applications should not be messing with it.

と説明されているように、プログラムからのアクセスは認められておらず、利用者の操作が前提とされています。

ですので、定義情報の場所を知ろうとすべきではありません。